# $f^{-1}(\{w_{0}\})$ is a linear subspace of $V$ iff $w_0 = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We have two $K$-Vectorspaces $V, W$ and $f \in L(V,W)$

Let $w_0 \in Image(f)$ such that $f^{-1}(\{w_{0}\}) := \{v \in V \ | \ f(v) = w_0\}$

First I have proved that $f^{-1}(\{w_{0}\})$ is an affine subspace of $V$ by showing that for $v_0 \in f^{-1}(\{w_{0}\})$

$U := f^{-1}(\{w_{0}\}) - v_0$ is a linear subspace of $V$

Now I would like to prove: $f^{-1}(\{w_{0}\})$ is a linear subspace of $V$ iff $w_0 = 0$

On one direction, if $w_0 = 0$ then is $Kern(f)$ a subspace of $V$.
How would I go about the other direction? and why should this statement be true?

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! Just check whether the sum of two pre-images of $w_0$ is again one of its  pre-images. 5incidentally the inverse image  of a non-zero vector is called an *affine subspace*, wich a vector subspace that has been  translated.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :** If $f^{-1}(\{w_0\})$ is a vector subspace of $V$, it must contain $0$.